# Get Local Storage data and display on the page

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to display the 5 previous visited pages to the users on my website. I used HTML Web Storage API. I managed to display the first 5 pages. But, to display the 6th page I want to delete the 1st page and insert the 6th page in the place of 5th page (It's very confusing? I give an example :) I added time for verification

```
Page Title 6/4/2020, 9:17:35 PM
Page Title 6/4/2020, 9:17:33 PM
Page Title 6/4/2020, 9:17:30 PM
Page Title 6/4/2020, 9:17:27 PM
Page Title 6/4/2020, 9:17:23 PM
```

I don't know how to display the 6th page. If a user goes to the 6th page, it has to be displayed like this

```
Page Title 6/4/2020, 9:17:40 PM
Page Title 6/4/2020, 9:17:35 PM
Page Title 6/4/2020, 9:17:33 PM
Page Title 6/4/2020, 9:17:30 PM
Page Title 6/4/2020, 9:17:27 PM
```

But I can't get this. I am lost :( I tried this code so far. The latest visited page should be at the top followed by the previous 4 pages.

```js
var arr = ['LINK1', 'LINK2', 'LINK3', 'LINK4', 'LINK5'];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (localStorage.getItem(arr[i]) == null) {
    localStorage.setItem(arr[i], document.title + ' ' + new Date().toLocaleString());
    //localStorage.removeItem(arr[(i+1)%5]); I added this line, but I did not get expected result
    break;
  }
}

var1 = '';

for (i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (localStorage.getItem(arr[i]) != null) {
    var1 = var1 + localStorage.getItem(arr[i]) + '<br>';
  }
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = var1;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="result"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I think the code will not work here since I can't access the local storage of SO. Help me

Comment: This code will set five items in local storage to the same value (the title of the current page plus a date value which is unlikely to change all that much in the loop), then get those five values out of local storage and display them.

Comment: Here is the working of my code https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GFGPXHFYHC09

Comment: If I get you right, you want to push the new site onto the list of sites you already have?

Comment: @Doc-Han Yes, I want to push the new web page in the list of 5 web pages. The 6th web page should be replaced with the 1st web page (First entered)

Comment: What are the for loops doing? can you explain further

Comment: @Doc-Han Here is the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GFGPXHFYHC09) to test

Answer (score 0):

The code below removes 5 from the list and adds 500 in front of the list

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

let n = 500;

for(let i=5;i>0;i--){
  let j = i-1;
  arr[i] = arr[j];
}
arr[0] = n;
arr.pop();

console.log(arr);
```